# Types of books or Types of book?

Tags: grammar

can anybody tell me which one of these is the correct one? I have been searching all over the internet but I have still got no answer.

> Types of books
>
> Types of book

Comment: This has been answered thoroughly on the English Language and Usage SE.  The difference lies in [countable versus uncountable quantities](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/types-of-things-vs-types-of-thing) ([also here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29843/types-of-followed-by-singular-or-plural)).  "Types of literature" (uncountable) vs "Types of books" (countable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct, though *types of books* is more common, especially in American English. Here are links to frequency graphs of "types of book" vs. "types of books" in the Google Ngram Viewer:

- [in the "American English" corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=types+of+book%2Ctypes+of+books&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3)
- [in the "British English" corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=types+of+book%2Ctypes+of+books&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3)